# aws lambda node js returns escaped JSON for object instance

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this simple class definition :

```
function FlatField(id, content) {

  if ( content === undefined ) content = '';

  this.id = id;
  this.content = content;

}
```

In AWS lambda, why will the following code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var test = { id: 103, content: "fred" };
    callback(null, test );
};
```

return the following clean JSON

```
{
  "id": 103,
  "content": "fred"
}
```

while the following code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var test = new FlatField( 103, 'fred' );
    callback(null, test );
};
```

will return the following escaped JSON

```
"{\"id\":103,\"content\":\"fred\"}"
```

?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you've proven the serializer  works differently for object literals than for functions!

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I fix this then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've proven some serialization code further downstream works differently for object literals than for constructor functions! Though it's gross, you'd have to do something like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var test = new FlatField( 103, 'fred' )
    callback(null, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test)) )
}
```

I suppose you could make yourself a utility function that took care of this.

I'd consider making Flatfield a plain function that returns an object literal. Then the problem goes away:

```
function flatField(id, content) {
  if ( content === undefined ) content = ''
  return {id,content}
}
```